# windows command-line usage or creating a bat file with specific commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I got big folder with bin files and got a programm with wich i can decode them.
Can't just figure out how to run it for every file in folder with exact extension and create same output name using input file name.

Example how it works through cmd.exe

> DecodeTSubBand 1.bin 1.wav

So it's create 1.wav file

"1.bin" is input filename and "1.wav" is output filename

Also i can't understand what to do when it comes to next file (2.wav for example), it's just overwrite first 1.wav file over and over again.

Thanks!

Comment: A batch file is just a text file that executes one command after another.  All you need to do is put each command on a separate line and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [for](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900%28v=ws.11%29.aspx) to loop through the folder and run a command on each file. Something like this should work for you. You don't need a batch file - you can run this from the command line. (If you *must* have a batch file, just double the *%* characters.)

```
for %f in (*.bin) do DecodeTSubBand %f %~nf.wav
```

Before running it, I usually check to make sure it's going to do what I want first by replacing the command with `echo`. Doing so in this case will show you what it does when it reaches *2.bin* and *2.wav*.

```
for %f in (*.bin) do echo %f %~nf.wav
```

Comment: Thank you so much, will try and reply how it works.

Comment: Amazing! Worked like a charm, thank you so much, you saved a huge amount of my time. ~oxoxo